# How to evaluate stacked classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, stacking

I have 2 sets of classifiers, both trained on 2 different feature sets extracted from the same data.

I would like to combine them using the "stacking" method, which I understand as follows:

1. Have the predictions from the initial classifiers
2. Use these predictions as input to another classifier
3. This final classifier predicts and outputs the predicted class of the stacking model

My question is about using a separate test set in order to evaluate this. What I am thinking is:

1. Predict on the test set using the initial classifiers
2. Use these predictions as input to the fitted final classifier that I trained before
3. The output of this classifier will be the predictions of the test set.

Is this logic correct? Or do I need to train the "initial classifiers" for the test data?

Comment: The idea of stacking is to combine multiple forecasts into one, so say you have 5 models, each with its own predictions. You obtain all 5 forecasts and then you aggregate them somehow (for ex. average) and then you evaluate these final forecasts once on the same test set. If you are using a different test set for each model then there is no aggregating to be done, hence no stacking.

Comment: @user2974951 The way I want to aggregate is by using their outputs to train lets say a Logistic Regression (the most usual). But I can't make predictions with this final LR directly on the test set, since the test set has m number of features but the LR is trained on 5 features (output of initial models). The question is on which is the correct way to "process" the test set in order to be able to feed it to this LR model for the final predictions.